# Convert String to Double - VB

Tags: vb.net, string, double, try-catch

Is there an efficient method in VB to check if a string can be converted to a double?

I'm currently doing this by trying to convert the string to a double and then seeing if it throws an exception. But this seems to be slowing down my application.

```
Try
    ' if number then format it.
    current = CDbl(x)
    current = Math.Round(current, d)
    Return current
Catch ex As System.InvalidCastException
    ' item is not a number, do not format... leave as a string
    Return x
End Try
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try looking at Double.TryParse() if you are using .NET 1.1/2.0/3.0/3.5/4.0/4.5

Comment: Unlike the other TryParse methods, Double.TryParse has been around since at least .NET 1.1 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 26):

> VB.NET Sample Code

```
Dim A as String = "5.3"
Dim B as Double

B = CDbl(Val(A)) '// Val do hard work

'// Get output 
MsgBox (B) '// Output is 5,3 Without Val result is 53.0
```

Comment: This one worked converting a string to double.  I'd tried Convert.ToDouble, cdbl and the Double.TryParse.  But it took a Val() to actually do the job.

Comment: Best solution I found here in SO :-)

Answer (score 12):

```
Dim text As String = "123.45"
Dim value As Double
If Double.TryParse(text, value) Then
    ' text is convertible to Double, and value contains the Double value now
Else
    ' Cannot convert text to Double
End If
```

Answer (score 4):

The international versions:

```
    Public Shared Function GetDouble(ByVal doublestring As String) As Double
        Dim retval As Double
        Dim sep As String = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator

        Double.TryParse(Replace(Replace(doublestring, ".", sep), ",", sep), retval)
        Return retval
    End Function

    ' NULLABLE VERSION:
    Public Shared Function GetDoubleNullable(ByVal doublestring As String) As Double?
        Dim retval As Double
        Dim sep As String = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator

        If Double.TryParse(Replace(Replace(doublestring, ".", sep), ",", sep), retval) Then
            Return retval
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Function
```

Results:

```
        ' HUNGARIAN REGIONAL SETTINGS (NumberDecimalSeparator: ,)

        ' Clean Double.TryParse
        ' -------------------------------------------------
        Double.TryParse("1.12", d1)     ' Type: DOUBLE     Value: d1 = 0.0
        Double.TryParse("1,12", d2)     ' Type: DOUBLE     Value: d2 = 1.12
        Double.TryParse("abcd", d3)     ' Type: DOUBLE     Value: d3 = 0.0

        ' GetDouble() method
        ' -------------------------------------------------
        d1 = GetDouble("1.12")          ' Type: DOUBLE     Value: d1 = 1.12
        d2 = GetDouble("1,12")          ' Type: DOUBLE     Value: d2 = 1.12
        d3 = GetDouble("abcd")          ' Type: DOUBLE     Value: d3 = 0.0

        ' Nullable version - GetDoubleNullable() method
        ' -------------------------------------------------
        d1n = GetDoubleNullable("1.12") ' Type: DOUBLE?    Value: d1n = 1.12
        d2n = GetDoubleNullable("1,12") ' Type: DOUBLE?    Value: d2n = 1.12
        d3n = GetDoubleNullable("abcd") ' Type: DOUBLE?    Value: d3n = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

I simple used `Eval(string)` and it evaluated as Double.