# Creating a BMI App

Tags: vb.net, vba, visual-studio

I'm trying to make a simple BMI app and I'm trying to get it so when you input your weight and height, it'll do the math.

Of course I get "Implicit conversions from 'String' to 'Double'"

Here's the catch: It gave it to me when I was trying to convert the string to text; however now it's giving me the error on line 1 when I only have Option Strict on that line.

So I was wondering how would I go about using the right arithmetic to solve this? I'm starting out with VB.net, and right now just can't understand what I'm doing right.

I've looked at another post, and oddly I'm still trying to figure it out as I haven't learned about Double.TryParse() yet.

Here's the code:

```
        Dim strbmi As String
    Dim strHeight As String
    Dim strweight As String
    Dim decbmi As Decimal


    strweight = txtWeight.Text
    strHeight = txtHeight.Text
    strbmi = lblBMI.Text

    If IsNumeric(txtHeight) Then
        strHeight = Convert.ToString(txtHeight.Text)
    End If
    If IsNumeric(txtHeight) Then
        strHeight = Convert.ToString(txtHeight.Text)
    End If
    If IsNumeric(txtWeight) Then
        strweight = Convert.ToString(txtWeight.Text)
    End If

    If decbmi <= 18.5 Then
        lblBMICategory.Text = "Underweight"
    ElseIf decbmi <= 25 Then
        lblBMICategory.Text = "Normal Weight"

    ElseIf decbmi <= 30 Then
        lblBMICategory.Text = "Overweight"
    ElseIf decbmi > 30 Then
        lblBMICategory.Text = "Obesity"
    End If
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert String to Double - VB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172306/convert-string-to-double-vb)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe you are mistaking some concepts. For all practical effects, string *is* text. You must first cast it as numeric (and catch and treat errors you may get there), and then do the math. Here's what I think you should have done:

```
Function BMI(strHeight As String, strweight As String) As String
    Dim dblHeight, dblWeight As Double
    If Not Double.TryParse(strHeight, dblHeight) Then Return "Invalid Entry: Height"
    If Not Double.TryParse(strweight, dblWeight) Then Return "Invalid Entry: Weight"
    Dim dblBMI = dblWeight / (dblHeight ^ 2)
    If dblBMI <= 18.5 Then
        Return "Underweight"
    ElseIf dblBMI <= 25 Then
        Return "Normal Weight"
    ElseIf dblBMI <= 30 Then
        Return "Overweight"
    Else
        Return "Obesity"
    End If
End Function
```