# Currency values calculating error in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have created a small currency calculation program in vb.net. But when I am calculating two currency values, it is showing the wrong amount. My text boxes are already in currency format. Kindly looking for your help please.

Here is my code for calculation:

```
txtBalance.Text = Val(txtPayment.Text) + Val(txtTotalAmount.Text)
```

Comment: What is the exact content of the two textboxes that you are trying to convert in a number?

Comment: If I calculate two currency value, $650.00 and $5000.00 it should get output $5650.00 but I'm getting output 655 which is totally wrong calculation.

Comment: You need to convert the content of the textbox you should try: `CDbl(Val(txtPayment.Text))` try looking at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172306/convert-string-to-double-vb

Comment: Do not use Visual Basic methods. You are writing code in vb.net. You need convert text to decimal type. `Dim payment = Decimal.Parse(txtPayment.Text)`

Comment: `String = (Assumed number from string) + (Assumed number from string)` - adding apples and wanting oranges! Should be `Number = (parsed number from string) + (parsed number from string)`

Comment: How is $5000 being written? My guess is that its as `5,000` and `,` is being treated as a decimal separator so it is parsing it as just 5. Please include the exact values of `txtTotalAmount.Text` and `txtPayment.Text`.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextBox3.Text = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox1.Text) + Convert.ToDouble(TextBox2.Text)
```

Also

[How do I convert from a string to an integer in Visual Basic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708838/how-do-i-convert-from-a-string-to-an-integer-in-visual-basic)